# uploadify + backbone events problem

Tags: uploadify, backbone.js

I have a multiple files uploadify setting with:

```
'onComplete' : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
    myCollection.add({params parsed from response json});
}
```

which triggers (trough this.collection.bind('add', this.add)) this collection view method:

```
add: function(obj) {
    var view = new MyModelView({model: obj});
    this.$('.insert-models-here').append(view.render().el);
    return this;
},
```

The `new MyModelView` call triggers: `MyModelView::initialize()` which is here:

```
initialize: function() {
    var t = $('#photo-template').html();
    this.template = _.template(t);
    this.model.view = this;
},
```

And every _.template() calls jumps inside `__flash__toXML()` method from which all thread is stopped.
The result is no model added inside my collection from any uploadify event.

Does anyone knows why and how to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found solution.

Problem was in using underscore in uploadify events so I replace underscore _.templates with [icanhaz](http://icanhazjs.com/) and rewrite my add() collection view method this way to workaround any underscore functionality:

```
    add: function(obj) {
        var view = new MyModelView({model: obj});
        $('.insert-models-here').first().append(view.render().el);
        return this;
    },
```

Hope someone will call my name in future..